# Stuck on the usage of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-activity

I am trying to pass the image I pick from gallery to another activity. Beside this, in same class, i have several `editText` to get data from user. To take data from `editText` and pass on `SecondActivity` i use `Intent`:

```
save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);

            intent.putExtra("name", Name);
            intent.putExtra("company", Company);
            intent.putExtra("phone", Phone);
            intent.putExtra("mobile", Mobile);
            intent.putExtra("address", Address);
            intent.putExtra("email", Email);
            intent.putExtra("website", Website);
            intent.putExtra("title", Title); 

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And in order i have 'SwitchCase' 'onActivityResult' where i use for picking image and set on `imageView` on `FirstActivity`. This is `openGallery` intent for double `onActivityResult`:

```
private void openGallerylogo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}
private void openGalleryqr() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 2);
}
```

SwitchCase onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);

    switch(1){
    case 1:

    if (requestCode == 1) 
    {
        if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {              

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String PicPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

    logoview.setBackgroundResource(0);
    logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath1));

    break;
        }}  


    case 2:
        if (requestCode == 2) 
        {
            if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
            {              

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();                     
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                cursor.moveToFirst();                   
                String PicPath2 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
    qrcodeview.setBackgroundResource(0);
    qrcodeview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath2));
    break;
}}

    }

    }
```

So now main thing is where to insert below code:

```
    final Intent newdata = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
    newdata.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);
    newdata.putExtra("picture_path2", PicPath2);
    startActivity(newdata);
```

Normally, i have to insert in body of `save.setOnClickListener` and get data+images to pass `SecondActivity` as i do for `editText`. But i have clash for Second Intent.

Or I can insert as:

```
logoview.setBackgroundResource(0);
logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath1));
Intent newdata = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
newdata.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);

startActivity(newdata);
```

Then it works but intent starts immediately and i am unable to `setText` above. Thank you for your helps.

---

This is all my code in the class:

```
package com.example.mapcard;

public class NewCard extends Activity {

ImageView logoview,qrcodeview, location;
Bitmap bmp1,bmp2;
Button save,clear;
public String count="logo";
EditText txtName,txtCompany,txtPhone,txtMobile,txtAddress,txtEmail,txtWebsite,txtTitle;


//  public String url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Android/data/com.example.mapcard/Mapcard/BusinessCard/";
public String filename = "Mapcard.csv";
//  public String fileContent;

ReadCSV csv;
StringBuffer filePath;
//String picPath1;
File file;

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mapcard.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);


    txtName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtCompany= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCompany);
    txtPhone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
    txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
    txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);


filePath = new StringBuffer();

   filePath.append("/sdcard/Android/data/");
    //filePath.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Android/data/com.example.mapcard/Mapcard/BusinessCard/");
    file = new File(filePath+filename.toString());

    csv = new ReadCSV(file);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//              GenerateCsv.generateCsvFile1(url, filename, fileContent);

            csv.writeHeader(txtName.getText().toString()+ "," 
                    +txtCompany.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtPhone.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtMobile.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtAddress.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtEmail.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtWebsite.getText().toString()
                    + "," +txtTitle.getText().toString());


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //    startActivity(new Intent(NewCard.this, Main.class));


            EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            EditText txtCompany= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCompany);
            EditText txtPhone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
            EditText txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
            EditText txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            EditText txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            EditText txtWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
            EditText txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);


            String Name=txtName.getEditableText().toString(),
            Company=txtCompany.getEditableText().toString(), Phone=txtPhone.getEditableText().toString(), 
            Mobile=txtMobile.getEditableText().toString(), Address=txtAddress.getEditableText().toString(), 
            Email=txtEmail.getEditableText().toString(), Website=txtWebsite.getEditableText().toString(), 
            Title=txtTitle.getEditableText().toString();                

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);

            intent.putExtra("name", Name);
            intent.putExtra("company", Company);
            intent.putExtra("phone", Phone);
            intent.putExtra("mobile", Mobile);
            intent.putExtra("address", Address);
            intent.putExtra("email", Email);
            intent.putExtra("website", Website);
            intent.putExtra("title", Title); 

              startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen Cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txtName.getText().clear();
            txtCompany.getText().clear();
            txtPhone.getText().clear();
            txtMobile.getText().clear();
            txtAddress.getText().clear();
            txtEmail.getText().clear();
            txtWebsite.getText().clear();               
            txtTitle.getText().clear();


        }
    });



    location=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.location);
    location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //  startActivity(new Intent(NewCard.this, GoogleMap.class));

        EditText txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);

        String Address=txtAddress.getEditableText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, GoogleMap.class);

        intent.putExtra("address", Address);

        startActivity(intent);  

    }

    });

    logoview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoview);
    logoview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {            

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(NewCard.this, Logo.class));
            count="logo";

       //               openGallery1();
            openGallerylogo();
        }


    }); 

    qrcodeview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrcodeview);
    qrcodeview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {            


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            count="qr";
  //                openGallery();
            openGalleryqr();

        }
    }); 



}

private void openGallerylogo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}
private void openGalleryqr() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 2);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);



    switch(1){
    case 1:

    if (requestCode == 1) 
    {
        if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {              

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String PicPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

                // intent.getExtras().get("data");

        //    startActivity(newdata);

                 //             if(bmp1 != null && !bmp1.isRecycled())


//              ImageView logoview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoview);
//              logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
        //  bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath1);

 //             if (count.equals("logo")){

                logoview.setBackgroundResource(0);
                logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath1));
                Intent newdata = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
                newdata.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);
 //newdata.putExtra("picture_path2", PicPath2);
                startActivity(newdata);



                 //   newdata.putExtra("picture_path2", PicPath2);

            break;
        }}  


    case 2:
        if (requestCode == 2) 
        {
            if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
            {              

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();                     
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                cursor.moveToFirst();                   
                String PicPath2 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();




                    qrcodeview.setBackgroundResource(0);
            qrcodeview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PicPath2));              

        break;

        }}

    }

    }


 //     final Intent newdata = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
 //     newdata.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);
 //     newdata.putExtra("picture_path2", PicPath2);
//      startActivity(newdata);
//      
//  }

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Comment: Can u just post the code wt u did for now.. so i can help u out.. i mean from where the intent is getting started

Comment: Thanks for concern. Above is already my code. I just don't know where to put 2nd intent. If you check above i already have one intent for editTexts. And second is 

Intent newdata = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
newdata.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);

startActivity(newdata);

Comment: can u post ur complete code. its in bits n pieces confusing

Comment: Side note, don't start java variables with a capital letter like `intent.putExtra("name", Name);`

Comment: switch(1) will always invoke case 1 never 2 unless you forget to insert a break

Comment: i have a break actually. and i changed switch(1) into switch(requestCode)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but if all you are worried about is the text getting updated before the next activity starts, just use a handler so that the textview has a chance to render

Comment: @GregGiacovelli I am trying to settle Intent which has PicPath1 and PicPath2 since i already have 1 intent in 'send' onClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the picpaths as instance variables to your activity. Manage them like any other lifecyled instance variable (via `onSaveInstanceState()`, and `onCreate(Bundle)`) and have your onClickListener reference them there.

```
String mPicPath1, mPicPath2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

   mPicPath1 = null;
   mPicPath2 = null; // or restore these from the icicle Bundle
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
    case 1:
        if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {              

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mPicPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            logoview.setBackgroundResource(0);
            logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicPath1));
        }
    break;  
    case 2:
        if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {              

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();                     
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            cursor.moveToFirst();                   
            mPicPath2 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            qrcodeview.setBackgroundResource(0);
            qrcodeview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicPath2));
        }
    break;
    }
    View saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save);
    // If the image paths are required before the activity can be started you can do this
    if (saveButton != null) {
       saveButton.setEnabled( !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPicPath1) &&  !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPicPath2));
    }
}
```

Then in your save button part:

```
save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);

        intent.putExtra("name", Name);
        intent.putExtra("company", Company);
        intent.putExtra("phone", Phone);
        intent.putExtra("mobile", Mobile);
        intent.putExtra("address", Address);
        intent.putExtra("email", Email);
        intent.putExtra("website", Website);
        intent.putExtra("title", Title); 
        // Add your picture paths if they are appropriate
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mPicPath1)) {
            intent.putExtra("picture_path1", PicPath1);
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mPicPath2)) {
           intent.putExtra("picture_path2", PicPath2);
        }
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: How to thank you! You make my day. I was trying to solve this complicated issue, finally done. Thank you so much @GregGiacovelli

Comment: By the way: when i use String type for mPicPath1 and mPicPath2, i can't use Bitmap resize or in other words, inSampleSize function. Can you suggest me a solution to pull image sizes smaller since i can't import big size images and having bitmap size exceed VM budget error. Thx @GregGiacovelli

Comment: I don't understand the limitation with the path being a string and able to resize it? I would say just scale down at the time of decode with the BitmapFactory.Options